# Merging duplicate accounts in Apex - Governor limits

Tags: apex, merge

I am trying to find duplicate accounts in the system and trying to merge them based on our filter criteria using apex.
The issue is I am hitting the governor limit of 150 DML statements while doing this.

We will have to put the merge statement inside the loop as we need the parent and child as the parameters in the merge statement.
I don't think we can bulkify Merge like other DML statements due to the above reason.
I am not sure if there is any better way to do it and avoid hitting governor limits.

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Code that I have tried is included below

```
global class LoyaltyAccountBatch implements Database.batchable<sObject>{ 


    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.batchableContext info){ 

        String query;
        query = ('SELECT  Id FROM  LoginHistory LIMIT 1');

        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
   }  

   global void execute(Database.batchableContext info, List<LoginHistory> scope){ 



        // Get those records based on the IDs
        List<Account> templst1 = [SELECT Id,UniqID from account where createddate = LAST_N_DAYS:4 and UniqID <> '']; 


         system.debug('templist is '+templst1);    


        Set<String> insertedRecords = new Set<String>() ;   

    for (Account a : templst1)  {
        insertedRecords.add(a.UniqID);
    }

               List<Account> templst = [SELECT Id,UniqID from account where NewUniqID IN : insertedRecords 
                                 order by NewUniqID,UniqID asc];

       // Process records 
        for(integer i=0;i+1<templst.size();i++) 
        {
            if(templst[i].UniqID <  templst[i+1].UniqID)        
            {
                system.debug('ids are '+templst[i].UniqID+'-->'+templst[i+1].UniqID);
                String str = '1'+templst[i].UniqID.substring(1,templst[i].UniqID.length());
                String str1 = '1'+templst[i+1].UniqID.substring(1,templst[i+1].UniqID.length());
                system.debug('str is'+str);
                system.debug('str1 is'+str1);
                if(str.equals(str1))
                {
                    Merge templst[i+1] templst[i];
                    system.debug('value of i is'+i);
                } 
            }
        }   

   }     

   global void finish(Database.batchableContext info){     
   } 

}
```

Comment: So...can you share what you have tried? It should be no problem in a batch where you can control the batch size.

Comment: OK, I must be missing something then as I have written a batch. I have edited the question to include my code. Please check it now.

Comment: That doesn't really look like de-duplication...you never check if the two values are equal. Don't you just want to merge records that have the same `UniqueId__c`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Ah. Right. That's not the purpose of the start method...

Comment: @AdrianLarson thanks for the responses. From the looks of it, it doesn't look like its de duplication but infact it is. To give a bit of context - we have a legacy system which sends us the account details which are inserted using Jitterbit. They have decided to modify the unique id ( which was based on each location before) to a new format, which would be 1 followed by the last digits. So after the cut off date the same account would come with a new format id and then only way was to merge them based on the criteria. NewUniqID is a formula created by us to check .

Comment: Okay, however the de-duplication method works, you have to query the `Account` records (or possibly an aggregate) in your `start` method. Standard de-duplication is easier because it is clear you can use aggregates and ensure all duplicates are within the same batch.

Comment: Yes, I get your point regarding the start method.I will try it. Thanks heaps @AdrianLarson.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I was able to do it by moving my initial query to start method and Limits.getLimitDmlStatements() but was not able to use aggregate result as NewUniqID which is column which has duplicate values is a formula field. Thanks again as I was dumb not use the start method in the first instance.

Comment: @AdrianLarson My other question is I am also writing an after insert trigger which calls an asynchronous method but that would also have a DML issue once the number of DML operation crosses 150. Is there any way to mitigate it ?

Comment: @Bob separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly are missing the point of the batch. Query the records you want to merge in your `start` method, not your `execute` method. By doing so, you then control how many records you pass to each `execute` block. Your de-duplication strategy is somewhat confusing, but if you just want to merge records that have the same `UniqueId__c` value, I recommend batching over `AggregateResult` here.

```
public List<AggregateResult> start(...)
{
    return Database.getQueryLocator([
        SELECT UniqueId__c FROM Account
        GROUP BY UniqueId__c
        HAVING count(Id) > 1
    ]);
}
public void execute(...)
{
    Map<String, List<Account>> accounts = new Map<String, List<Account>>();
    for (AggregateResult aggregate : scope)
        accounts.put((String)aggregate.get('UniqueId__c'));
    for (Account record : [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name IN :accounts.keySet()])
        accounts.get(record.Name).add(record);

    for (List<Account> duplicates : accounts.values())
        merge duplicates[0] duplicates[1];
}
public void finish(...)
{
}
```

If you pursue a strategy similar to the above, you will be able to limit the scope size at execution time to actually control how many records you try to de-duplicate in one go.

```
Database.executeBatch(new MyBatch(), /*scope_size*/ Limits.getLimitDmlStatements());
```

Obviously the `execute` code could use some refinement, such as error handling and considerations if there are more than two records with the same name. The above should help get you started, though.